# Replace outer span-tag using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the javascript replace method, I want to find this string:

```
<span class="memberX"><span class="member19">text</span></span>    <---X is any number
```

final output should be:

```
<span class="member19">text</span>
```

Essentially I want to remove the outer span which can have a class of memberX, where X is any number.

Comment: [Regex should not be used to do anything that includes HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)

Comment: Do you mean you have an input string containing html that includes that particular text, or do you want to find these elements on the current page?

Comment: use DOM manipulation functions, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in the DOM, you don't want regex. You should just manipulate the DOM itself.

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^=member] > span[class^=member]');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(spans[i], spans[i].parentNode);
    spans[i].parentNode.removeChild(spans[i].nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: +1 /me suggests DOM walking, other answerer comes with `querySelectorAll`, mind blown. :D

Comment: +1. Just before seeing your answer I was thinking about how easy it would be with jQuery with the same selector you used: `​$('span[class​​​​​​​​​​​​^="member​​​​​​​​"] > span[class^="member"]').unwrap();`. Nice answer.

Comment: nnnnnn, I like your answer. One question, how would I achieve this if I'm not manipulating the DOM directly but passed a block of HTML content in a variable? I then have to manipulate the variable and set the new value to itself?

Comment: @Chad: `var div = document.createElement("div"); div.innerHTML = myhtml;` Then use `div` as the root instead of `document`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) first.
2. Read up on the Document Object Model (in short DOM).
3. Use the DOM functions that JS provides to walk the DOM tree.
4. Write a traversal algorithm that walks over the DOM tree.
5. For each `span` element you come across, check if it has a single child which is also a span. If that's the case, you should replace the parent `span` by the child `span` if it fits your case.